# cannont find lGL

Tags: opengl, compiler-construction, ubuntu

Question: why can't it find -lGL?

---

Info: I wrote a program as guided by [this site](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux%3a_GLX_and_Xlib) on my netbook this morning and it compiled and ran with no problem. I then proceeded to take the exact same code and try to run it on my desktop. the version my netbook compiled worked, but it yelled at me because my netbook doesn't have a graphics card and my desktop does so it wasn't quite compiled right. still ran though.

But when I tried to compile it on my desktop it failed. at first it was saying "Fatal error: GL/gl.h: no such file or directory" so i thought "wait, i thought opengl came with ubuntu, I mean my netbook worked, maybe I installed something and forgot about it" so i ran through apt and pulled down everything opengl I felt might help. but staring at 212 - 1278  packages (depending on what words i search with) that may or may not be opengl related, I don't know what else to try. I got past the first problem, but now it is complaining that it can't find -lGL, which seems really odd.

any tips, tricks, comments, quips? My end objective is to be able to compile c code from the command line, I've been using the command that I got from the afore mentioned site:

```
gcc -o gltest gltest.c -lX11 -lGL -lGLU
```

I run Ubuntu 11.04 desktop, 64-bit. Nvidia GTX465.

Comment: Do you run a 64-bits Ubuntu on your netbook too ? This could be the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler was looking for a lib called libGL.so in /usr/lib, which was a symbolic link to /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so, Mesa's libGL. You also have the libGL from your nVidia drivers (which are probably in 275.28 version, see the libGL name : libGL.so.275.28). Modifying the symlink to point to nVidia's one gives your compiler no longer the Mesa's one, but the nVidia's one.

Answer (score 6):

try to install the following packages:

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglut3-dev
```

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=GL%2Fgl.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=natty&arch=any indicates `mesa-common-dev`

Comment: @tripleee: well, I could be wrong. I installed it on my system a lot of time ago :)

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but Mesa is supposed to provide openGL support if your system lacks dedicated hardware. My desktop has a graphics card, so I feel like mesa should matter. but I'll try it as soon as i get back to my dorm room. if i get mesa package, will the program still run on my graphics card?

Comment: i copy>pasted your command above and it said all packages are already at the newest version.

Comment: Mesa is also used for the open sources drivers like ATI ones. I don't know for the proprietary ones... But there's no difference between a chipset and a dedicated GPU in terms of libraries to use.

Comment: @Narcolapser: Btw, do you use proprietary drivers or Nouveau ?

Comment: good to know about libraries, thanks. i believe I'm using proprietary drivers as I'm using the most recent drivers provided by nvidia: http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html is it possible that nouveau would remedy my problem? Also, I intend to start working with openCL as well as soon as I get openGL working. Nouveau support that?

Comment: @Narcolapser: I don't think OpenCL will work with Nouveau. Can you paste the output of `ls -la /usr/lib/libGL.so.*` please ?

Comment: from my desktop it output: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 2011-09-21 10:40 /usr/lib/libGL.so.l-> libGL.so.275.28 \n -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1023120 2011-09-21 10:40 /user/lib/libGL.so.275.28 \n on my netbook it would only run if I removed the last ".*" it gave me: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 2011-09-12 12:56 libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so
that help?

Comment: Can you check if you have a /usr/lib/libGL.so link pointing on /usr/lib/libGL.so.275.28 on your desktop ? I mistyped the last dot, it shouldn't be here…

Comment: assuming that "/usr/lib/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.275.28" is what you are looking for. yes. there are 2 others listed a side from that "/usr/lib/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so" and "/usr/lib/libGL.so.275.28" are things just not pointing to where they should be?

Comment: You can maybe try this : `rm /usr/lib/libGL.so && ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so

Comment: that did it. just in closing, can you comment about what i just did and how you figured it out? thanks! (or write an answer so the credit can go where it belongs.)